# Regex for Number format Validation

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-lookarounds

Help with regex to match for this Number pattern .. I need accept the input only in below formats.For implementing this validation logic i need regex.
I tried using following

```
/(^(([0-9]{5,6}[,])+[0-9]{5,6})$)|(^(([0-9]{1,5}\*[,])+[0-9]{1,5}\*)$)|(^(([0-9]{5,6}[,])+[0-9]{1,5}\*)$)|(^(([0-9]{1,5}\*[,])+[0-9]{1,5})$)/
```

But it is not matching all scenarios.

Following are the possible inputs

1. 1123*,2133*,123*,1*
2. 213433,123453,123*
3. 123333,123623,678123,12323,
4. 1123*,123445,166788,123333,..........

Conditions - Number can have length 5 or 6. Inputs must be separated by comma. If input has  *** (Wildcard search)** then max length cannot be greater than 5. *ex 123123*(Not allowed)*

Comment: Could you explain the pattern?

Comment: Isn't this the same question you asked an hour ago? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40535382/regex-for-number-series-validation

Comment: Minus the requirements - I added them

Comment: Please provide a simple, clear description of what inputs you want to match, including if and how commas are accepted. We don't know what you mean by saying "can extend to any number of times". Why would you say that "it is not matching all scenarios" and give as an example `1*` when you just said that "number can have length 5 or 6"?

Comment: @torazaburo i have updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I completely understand the requirements of the RegExp matching pattern, but here's a preliminary approach.

- As I understand you, *Numbers [to be matched] can have length 5 or 6* and that the matching pattern should be able to capture any amount of numbers that fit this description. For this part, I will assume there are no asterisk characters (*****) contained in a number sequence.

Let's assume we have a variable `input` that is assigned as a value the string `213433,123453,123*`. Then...

```
input.match(/\d{5,6}(?!\*)/g);
```

should capture parts of the `input` variable as so described. I noticed you were using character sets in your attempt (*i.e.*, the `[0-9]` part); the `\d` term accomplishes the same thing.The `(?!\*)` portion is used to check that the 5- or 6-digit sequence is not followed by an asterisk character. Note: You have to escape the asterisk.

- In the event an input does possess an asterisk character, the matched portion can be no longer than 5 characters. (I hope I'm understanding the prompt correctly)! For this, the following RegExp pattern worked for the (admittedly inexhaustive) two tests I ran. Note: This pattern retains (*i.e.*, matches/captures) the asterisk character as well as the number sequence.

We can assume that the `input` variable here is assigned to the string `1123*,2133*,123*,1*` for purposes of testing out the next RegExp match pattern.

```
input.match(/(\d+\*){1,5}/g);
```

If I'm not mistaken, the two match patterns can be conditionally combined using a simple OR (`|`) operator.

```
input.match(/\d{5,6}(?!\*)|(\d+\*){1,5}/g);
```

Hopefully, that helps a bit. As a final test, let's assign the `input` variable to the string `1123*,2133*,123*,1*,123333,123623,678123,12323` (I concatenated example inputs 1. and 3. that you provided for this). Then, running the statement directly above returns the array:

```
["1123*", "2133*", "123*", "1*", "123333", "123623", "678123", "12323"]
```

If you wanted to retrieve the matches WITHOUT any wildcard characters (*****), you could simply modify the expression as follows:

```
a.match(/\d{5,6}(?!\*)|(\d+\*){1,5}/g).map(val => val.replace('*', ''));
```

to get...

```
["1123, "2133", "123", "1", "123333", "123623", "678123", "12323"]
```

Answer (score 1):

This does not seem very complicated, if I understand the question.

```js
var x = ['1123*,2133*,123*,1*', '213433,123453,123*', '123333,123623,678123,12323', '1123*,123445,166788,123333'];

var re =  /\d{5,6}|\d{1,5}\*/g;

console.log(x.map(s => s.match(re)));
```